# What is the best method (if there is one) to import a set of functions in a module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator, javascript-decorators

I am trying to solve this:

I have a module, let's say "users", for which I have a service with basic database operations (find, findMany, save etc).

I want to create more modules which all have the same basic database operations but I don't want to have to write them all again

To make things easy, I have these 2 functions in an utils file:

```
export async function find<T extends Model>(model: T, query, options?): Promise<T> {
    return model.find(query)
}
```

and

```
export async function findOne<T extends Model>(model: T, query, options?): Promise<T> {
    return model.findOne(query)
}
```

How can I make it so I import each of this functions to a class (using TypeScript decorators or other TS magic)

I want to have something like this

```
import { attachAllBasicDatabaseMethods } from "./model-utils/operations"
export class UserController {
    @attachAllBasicDatabaseMethods()
    private constructor() {}
}
```

so in my controller i can use a method like this:

```
async getSomeUsers() {
    const users = await this.findMany(UserModel, this.query, this.options);
    return users;
}
```

The decorator idea is just something I have thought of, but I know there are some other methods of solving this

Or better: using that decorator with the model as the parameter automatically binds the model to the methods, so I can use this.find(this.query, this.options)

Comment: Why do you want them to be methods? Why not use them directly just as functions?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I know that this doesn't really solve anything, I just want to structure my project this way